# Extracting EXE Icons in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, icons, exe, extract

I'm looking for a way to extract Icons from EXE files on Linux.

How can I accomplish this on Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: This question has enough detail to answer adequately. It definitely isn't too broad.

Comment: Perfectly useful question, definitely not too broad, but more suited for superuser.com

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510338/5132 .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yo can use `wrestool` to extract the windows icons from .exe file

```
sudo apt-get install icoutils
wrestool -x -t 14 source.exe > output.ico
```

Comment: Extracts noise instead of icon in my case